# How to fetch parameters by name (HttpWebResponse)?

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I have an object `HttpWebResponse` which do a request a get results correctly.

I fetch the parameters this way:

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
```

However, is there a way to fetch a parameter value by giving a property the name?

Something like

```
string token = streamReader.GetValue("token");
```

Comment: What do you mean by a parameter value / token within an http response?

Comment: In my stream, the variable result contains token="3232" etc... I would like to get the value it's equal by fetching it as in my example

Comment: What format is the response? XML? JSON? HTML?  You'll have to parse that text to get at the parameters.

Comment: @PeterRitchie what I though... I really have to parse the string?

Comment: Yep, but you can use serializers like JSON.net to make it easy

Comment: @PeterRitchie not familiar with this, is there a simple tutorial on this? I found many which seems way to complex for what I need to do

Comment: @cher are you actually getting a JSON response?  You need to know the format of the response before you can really parse it.  If it's not XML nor JSON, either of those serializers won't help.

Comment: @PeterRitchie this is what I get : "{\"code\":507,\"token\":\"28b4693fd00015d\"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is JSON, you can use JSON.NET to deserialize/parse the text into an object and then access properties of the object.  You can make use of a `dynamic` object so you don't have to define a type for serialization with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.  For example:

```
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
var token = o.token;
```

Comment: wow exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!! thx a lot!!